# How to use css to crop images from left and right without knowing dimensions

Tags: css, image

```
<div class="myImages">
    <%= image_tag data["images"].first["source"] %>
</div>

.myImages {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myImages img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;   
}
```

This works *almost* exactly how I need it to, except that images with a width initially greater than 100px are cropped from the right only instead of cropping from the left and right.

I have many images that I pull from an API that have variable dimensions, and I want to display them all on one page. If the width is less than 100px, the sides of the div fill up with black, which I like. But, for those images that have a width greater than 100px, I want to crop the left side and right sides equally until it is 100px.

For example, if this was a photo with a width greater than 100px

<--------------------Photo--------------------------->

Crop it this way:

<--Cropped--><-------Photo------><--Cropped-->

Is there a way to do that?

**Update, what I ended up using:**

```
.myImages {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.myImages img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;  
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property `object-fit: cover`. See [this](http://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/JYjBNP?editors=110) for an example.

Comment: I tweaked it a little bit, but your answer definitely put me on the write track. I've updated my post with what I'm using now